# Master replica not up-to-date with master

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have 2 Google Search Appliance machines.
The master has a fully up-to-date index however the master replica is not.

Where should I look to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the mirroring configuration and make sure it's configured correctly and active. You can tell from the admin console whether the GSA thinks it's mirror is up to date.

[GSA Help doco on Mirroring](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329210?hl=en)

[Mirroring Diagnostics Doco](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329210?hl=en#6ca8365b-2c41-44d2-ac9b-482b71cac5d6)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem: there was a connection error between master and slave.